# extract the adjacent character of selected letter

Tags: grep

I have this text file:

```
# cat letter.txt
this
is
just
a
test
to
check
if
grep
works
```

The letter "e" appear in 3 words.

```
# grep e letter.txt
test
check
grep
```

Is there any way to return the letter printed on left of the selected character?

```
expected.txt
t
h
r
```

Comment: What's the expected output if you append the word _erroneously_ to your list?

Comment: What if the line is `egg`? Should it print an empty string?

Comment: Yes. empty string if e is the first character in the word.

Comment: And what if there are multiple `e`s like `element`?

Comment: 'lm' I am trying to find all the characters that "e" likes to follow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *positive lookahead* to match a character that is followed by an `e`, without making the `e` part of the match.

```
cat letter.txt | grep -oP '.(?=e)'
```

Answer (score 5):

With shown samples in `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk '/e/{print substr($0,index($0,"e")-1,1)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '             ##Starting awk program from here.
/e/{              ##Looking if current line has e in it then do following.
  print substr($0,index($0,"e")-1,1)
                  ##Printing sub string from starting value of index e-1 and print 1 character from there.
}
' Input_file      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed -nE 's/.*(.)e.*/\1/p' letter.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have this input file:

```sh
cat file
this
is
just
a
test
to
check
if
grep
works
egg
element
```

You may use this `grep + sed` solution to find letter or empty string before `e`:

```sh
grep -oE '(^|.)e' file | sed 's/.$//'
t
h
r


l
m
```

Or *alternatively* this single `awk` command should also work:

```sh
awk -F 'e' 'NF > 1 {
   for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print substr($i, length($i), 1)
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk` you can use empty string as FS to split the input as individual characters:

```
awk -v FS= '/[e]/ {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="e") print $(i-1)}' file
t
h
r
```

Excluding "e" at the beginning in the `for` loop.

- edited

> `empty string if e is the first character in the word`.

- For example, this input:

```
cat file2
grep
erroneously
egg
Wednesday
effectively
```

```
awk -v FS= '/^[e]/ {print ""} /[e]/ {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="e") print $(i-1)}' file2
r

n

W
n

f
v
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/(.)e/{s//\n\1\n/;s/^[^\n]*\n//;P;D}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing and enable extended regexp `-nE`.

Focus only on lines that meet the requirements i.e. contain a character before `e`.

Surround the required character by newlines.

Remove any characters before and including the first newline.

Print the first line (up to the second newline).

Delete the first line (including the newline).

Repeat.

N.B. The solution will print each such character on a separate line.

To print all such characters on their own line, use:

```
sed -nE '/(.e)/{s//\n\1/g;s/^/e/;s/e[^\n]*\n?//g;s/\B/ /g;p}' file
```

N.B. Remove the `s/\B /g` if space separation is not needed.